# How to extract a certain part of a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to extract the last 4 digits before ".txt" from this string:

```
09/14/2017 12:00:27 - mtbill_post_201709141058.txt 7577_Delivered: OK
```

Those represent the time at which that log was created and I want to display it as 10:58. I read from a file that has multiple lines similar to the one displayed.

```
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object {
$splitUp = $_ -split "_"
$SC=$splitUp[2] -split "_"
Write-Host $SC
$len = $SC.Length
$folder2 = $SC.Substring($len - 12, 42)
}
```

I tried separating the string by "_" and then counting the characters in the obtained string and tried separating by the "Substring" command, but I receive the following error.

> Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "StartIndex cannot
>   be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex"
>
> At line:6 char:5
>   +     $folder2 = $SC.Substring($len - 12, 42)
>
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regex "lookahead".

What you are searching for is a set of four digits followed by ".txt":

```
$string = "09/14/2017 12:00:27 - mtbill_post_201709141058.txt 7577_Delivered: OK"
$regex = "\d{4}(?=\.txt)"
[regex]::matches($string, $regex).value
```

Comment: `[regex]::match($string, $regex).Value.Insert(2,":")` to format as 10:58

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks Mark Wragg, I understand what happened now.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant solution:

```
$String = '09/14/2017 12:00:27 - mtbill_post_201709141058.txt 7577_Delivered: OK'

$String -Match '.*(?=\.txt)' | Out-Null
$Match = $Matches[0][-4..-1] -Join ''

$Time = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Match, 'HHmm',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$Time.ToShortTimeString()
```

- Uses RegEx to get all of the string before the .txt
- Uses the Array Index to get the characters from 4th to last to the last character and joins them together as a single string.
- Casts the value as a DateTime object using ParseExact to interpret it as 24 hour time code
- Outputs the Short Date value of that DateTime object.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have just a quick question. It might be stupid, but I am new at this and I really just want to properly understand what it happening. I don't get what does '.*(?=\.txt)' do. I understand it gets all the string before the .txt, but how? 
Thanks again!

Comment: Per the other answer (which for the  regex part is simpler/better and I recommend you upvote/accept) it's doing a regex "lookahead" which is saying match the pattern that is before the pattern denoted by `?=`. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with `Substring` and `IndexOf`:

```
$string="09/14/2017 12:00:27 - mtbill_post_201709141058.txt 7577_Delivered: OK"
$string.Substring($string.IndexOf('.txt')-4, 4)
```